# Winforms TextBox vertical alignment with FixedSingle border

Tags: winforms, textbox, alignment

When you change the BorderStyle property of a TextBox control to FixedSingle, the entered text is no longer properly vertically centered inside of the control. The padding on the bottom is much larger than on the top. How can I get rid of this?

This is on Windows 7.

[image: Textbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit of a turd.  One way to cheat is to change the border to none and paint the border around the borderless textbox in the container's paint event:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(textBox1.Left - 3, textBox1.Top - 3,
                            textBox1.Width + 5, textBox1.Height + 5);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, r);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.WindowFrame, r);
```

Results:

[image]